# How to merge two searchs in Elastic Kibana into one

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana

I have two different logs:
Log 1 with fields: message: "Log.Test.First.Message" and traceID: "123"
Log 2 with fields: message: "Log.Test.Second.Message" and traceID: "123"

How should I create the query in "Search" to find only these traceID which had both messages? I need it to create visualization.

For example: Logs in history:

```
Log 1 with message: Log.Test.First.Message and traceID "123"
Log 2 with message: Log.Test.First.Message and traceID "456"
Log 3 with message: Log.Test.Second.Message and traceID "123"
Log 4 with message: Log.Test.First.Message and traceID "789"
Log 5 with message: Log.Test.Second.Message and traceID "789"
```

and result after search should be: 2

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "traceID": "123" }},
        { "terms": { "message.keyword": ["Log.Test.First.Message", "Log.Test.Second.Message"] }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I think this should filter the ones with relevant terms.